# I called showMaximized() with QT4.7,A strange question came up

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, interface, qt4.7

That's what I would like to achieve:

[image]

But it turned out that way:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve], and [edit] your question to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem because I called QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);This caused showMaximized() to show the wrong result.So I've reimplemented these two functions。

```html
void MainWindowDef::showMax()
{
    oldSize = this->size();
    oldPoint = this->pos();
    resize(QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry().size());
    move(0, 0);
    isMax = true;
}

void MainWindowDef::showOld()
{
    resize(oldSize);
    move(oldPoint);
}
```